# "Person/entity paying for your trip" on DS-160

Tags: american-english

What do I put on my DS-160 for “person/entity paying for your trip”? Does it mean the entire funding or just the flight ticket to travel?

Comment: Entire trip (or at least the most important items).

Answer (score 4):

"Paying for your trip" means paying all the expenses associated with the trip - flights, accommodation, food etc. If different people are paying for different parts then say that and list them.